# The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Spring Boot v1.4.2.RELEASE application with JPA.

I defined repository interfaces and implementations

**ARepository**

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, String>, ARepositoryCustom, JpaSpecificationExecutor<A> {
}
```

**ARepositoryCustom**

```
@Repository
public interface ARepositoryCustom {
    Page<A> findA(findAForm form, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**ARepositoryImpl**

```
@Repository
public class ARepositoryImpl implements ARepositoryCustom {
    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;
    @Override
    public Page<A> findA(findAForm form, Pageable pageable) {
        return aRepository.findAll(
                where(ASpecs.codeLike(form.getCode()))
                .and(ASpecs.labelLike(form.getLabel()))
                .and(ASpecs.isActive()),
                pageable);
    }
}
```

And a service
**AServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class AServiceImpl implements AService {
    private ARepository aRepository;
    public AServiceImpl(ARepository aRepository) {
        super();
        this.aRepository = aRepository;
    }
    ...
}
```

My application won't start with the message :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

|  aRepositoryImpl
└─────┘
```

I followed all steps discribed in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour

Please help !

Laurent

Comment: Try to remove annotation `@Repository` from `ARepositoryCustom`

Comment: There is no need to mark `ARepositoryCustom` as `@Repository` because you want to provide it's implementation instead of generating it with Spring Data

Comment: You have an interface `ARepository` that extends `ARepositoryCustom` next in the implementation you use the interface `ARepository`. I doubt SPring Data Jpa will be able to figure things out. Also imho that method belongs in your service and not in your repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a simple fix for your original problem:
Just remove @Repository from ARepositoryCustom and from ARepositoryImpl.
Keep all the naming and interface/class hierarchies. They are all OK.

Answer (score 54):

Use `@Lazy`

A simple way to break the cycle is by asking Spring to initialize one of the beans lazily. That is: instead of fully initializing the bean, it will create a proxy to inject it into the other bean. The injected bean will only be fully created when it’s first needed.

NB:
Cyclic dependency Errors usually mean you have to take another look at your Architecture. Lazy loading will fix it but your code might be substandard.

```
@Service
public class AServiceImpl implements AService {
    private final ARepository aRepository;
    public AServiceImpl(@Lazy ARepository aRepository) {
        super();
        this.aRepository = aRepository;
    }
    ...
}
```

source: https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: Actually, the @lazy helped me

Comment: Thanks for adding the source because it helps to resolve the problem differently than `@lazy`

Answer (score 13):

Use @Lazy annotation it will be resolved

```
@Component
public class Bean1 {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private Bean2 bean2;
}
```

Comment: Not sure the `@Autowired` is needed - because of the `@Component`...

Answer (score 4):

I've tested your source code, and found something tricky.

First, with your source code, I got the following error:

```
There is a circular dependency between 1 beans in the application context:
- ARepositoryImpl (field private test.ARepository test.ARepositoryImpl.aRepository)
- aRepositoryImpl
```

Then, I guess Spring 'confused' between `ARepository` (JPA repository) and `ARepositoryImpl` (Custom repository). 
So, I would suggest you **rename** `ARepository` to something else, such as `BRepository`. It worked if I renamed the class name.

According to offcial documentation of Spring Data (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) :

> These classes need to follow the naming convention of appending the namespace element’s attribute repository-impl-postfix to the found repository interface name. **This postfix defaults to Impl**

Answer (score 4):

add this in your **pom.xml** file. It works for me

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references:true
```

Comment: Which doesn't really solve to underlying problem but rather just hides it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32181604)

Comment: I appreciate that this doesn't solve the root issue. However, I also appreciate having alternatives to potentially heavy refactoring exercises.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:
I added

```
spring:
   main:
    allow-circular-references: true
```

in the application.yml

Or you can add

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

in the application.properties

Both application.yml and application.properties files in the below directory:
[image]

Comment: From spring: "Relying upon circular references is discouraged". I would say, try to fix your issue instead of enabling the allow-circular-references property.

Answer (score 0):

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;

Add **@Lazy** on one dependency injection to make it lazy load.